# GCP pubsub topic metadata not being delivered

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a Google cloud storage bucket that in projectA that I am trying to configure to send notifications on object creation to a topic in projectB. I do this by the following terraform:

```
resource "google_storage_notification" "my_bucket_notification" {
  bucket             = "my_bucket"
  payload_format     = "JSON_API_V1"
  topic              = "projects/projectB_id/topics/my-topic"
  event_types        = ["OBJECT_FINALIZE"]
  object_name_prefix = "folderA/"
}
```

Over in projectB I create the binding to allow projectA to publish to a topic:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "my-topic" {
  name = "my-topic"
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "my-top-subscription" {
  name  = "my-subscription"
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.my-topic.name
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_member" "my_bucket_iam" {
  role   = "roles/pubsub.publisher"
  topic  = google_pubsub_topic.my-topic.id
  member = "serviceAccount:${var.projectAEmail}"
}
```

Whenever an object gets created in `folderA` a message is published over to my subscription in `projectB`. However, I notice that any metadata on the objects in `folderA` are missing from the notification. Looking at the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_notification) for terraform, there doesn't seem to be any setting that suggests excluding blob metadata. Is there a specific configuration I need to set to allow blob metadata to be passed in a pubsub notification from google cloud storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case of user error. In my case metadata was not always being sent on the first upload, but rather later on. Adding metadata does not create another version of the object in gcs. I was able to fix this by updating my pubsub topic declaration to:

```
event_types        = ["OBJECT_FINALIZE", "OBJECT_METADATA_UPDATE"]
```

. Then on my code side I ignore messages until the metadata was present.